# Implementing Repositories for nested entities

Tags: php, orm, ddd-repositories

I am trying to figure my way out of this problem. Trying to implement repositories in a project with a complex domain logic, some questions arise.

Say, you have blogs, which have posts, which have comments.

So I make a PostRepositoryInterface.

```
interface PostRepositoryInterface 
{
    public function findAll();

    public function findOneById($id);

    public function save(Post $post);
}
```

Then I do my Post Repository implementation for my NiceORM.

```
class NiceORMPostRepository implements PostRepositoryInterface {
     // Stuff
}
```

Now the question is how to I handle the nested comments.

I've found some answers out there, such as adding methods to the interface:

```
interface PostRepositoryInterface {
    // Old stuff

    public function findAllWithComments();
    public function findOneByIdWithComments($id);
}
```

I kind of feel a problem with this approach, specially when the entity grows and the amount of nested entities goes up.

I'd like to know your opinion about saving this complex entities, too.

Say we have posts with translations, and the way we handle the translations is something like...

```
$postQuery->withLanguages();
$post = $postQuery->findOne();
$post->language('en')->setTitle('Nice Post Title');
$post->save();
```

This saves the nested entity language.

How would you implement this with Repositories? Is it possible?

Thanks for all insights.